# HttpModule breaks WebResource.axd

Tags: asp.net, vb.net, httpmodule, webresource.axd

I wrote an HttpModule which does some simple content rewriting. It works fine, however it has a nasty side effect where the output of WebResource.axd is zero bytes. I've seen some references to this known issue online, but not with a filter quite like mine.

Am I doing something (or neglecting to) here that would cause WebResource.axd to break? I'm using ASP.NET 4.0 on IIS 7.5.

```
Imports System.Text
Imports System.Text.RegularExpressions
Imports System.IO
Imports System.Web

Namespace HttpModules

  Public Class ResponseRewritingModule
    Implements IHttpModule

    Public Sub Init(ByVal app As HttpApplication) Implements IHttpModule.Init
      AddHandler app.ReleaseRequestState, AddressOf Me.OnReleaseRequestState
    End Sub

    Public Sub Dispose() Implements IHttpModule.Dispose
    End Sub

    Public Sub OnReleaseRequestState(ByVal s As Object, ByVal e As EventArgs)
      Dim app As HttpApplication = CType(s, HttpApplication)
      If (app.Request.Url.ToString().Contains(".aspx")) Then
        app.Response.Filter = New ImageUrlResponseFilter(app.Response.Filter)
      End If
    End Sub

  End Class

  Public Class ImageUrlResponseFilter
    Inherits MemoryStream

    Private responseStream As Stream
    Private matchpattern As String = "src=""/Images/"
    Private matchpattern2 As String = "url\(/Images"
    Private matchpattern3 As String = "src = ""/Images/"
    Private matchpattern4 As String = "src=""http://www.mydomain.com/Images/"
    Private replacementstring As String = "src=""http://images.mydomain.com/Images/"
    Private replacementstring2 As String = "url(http://images.mydomain.com/Images"

    Public Sub New(inputStream As Stream)
      responseStream = inputStream
    End Sub

    Public Overrides Sub Write(buffer As Byte(), offset As Integer, count As Integer)

      Dim strBuffer As String = System.Text.UTF8Encoding.UTF8.GetString(buffer)

      If (Not HttpContext.Current.Request.IsSecureConnection) Then
        strBuffer = Regex.Replace(strBuffer, matchpattern, replacementstring, RegexOptions.Compiled Or RegexOptions.IgnoreCase)
        strBuffer = Regex.Replace(strBuffer, matchpattern2, replacementstring2, RegexOptions.Compiled Or RegexOptions.IgnoreCase)
        strBuffer = Regex.Replace(strBuffer, matchpattern3, replacementstring, RegexOptions.Compiled Or RegexOptions.IgnoreCase)
        strBuffer = Regex.Replace(strBuffer, matchpattern4, replacementstring, RegexOptions.Compiled Or RegexOptions.IgnoreCase)
        responseStream.Write(UTF8Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(strBuffer), offset, UTF8Encoding.UTF8.GetByteCount(strBuffer))
      Else
        ' Do nothing for SSL connections
        responseStream.Write(buffer, offset, count)
      End If

    End Sub

  End Class

End Namespace
```

**UPDATE:** Daniel Richardson seems to have discovered the root cause and has a solution here: http://daniel-richardson.blogspot.com/2008/11/how-to-apply-filter-to-content-returned.html

Microsoft has apparently known about this issue for years and WILL NOT FIX IT: http://connect.microsoft.com/VisualStudio/feedback/details/105150/webresource-axd-output-always-truncated-when-used-with-a-response-filter

Comment: What will StringBuilder gain me here? My question is why enabling this module breaks WebResource.axd. What do you mean by image filter?

Comment: ControlAdapter assumes I'm using <asp:Image> for all my images, no? This is definitely not the case. I've seen many benchmarks that disprove that StringBuilder will be faster in all cases. Anyway, my question is not about performance at all, but about why WebResource.axd breaks. If WebResource is as fragile as you suggest, nobody would use HttpModules, which is hardly true at all.

Comment: The link to Daniel Rochardson's blog is now invalid.  Does anyone know of an overview (or a link to the original article) that will shed some (specific) light on the resolution for this problem?

Comment: Looks like the specifics for Daniel Richardson's blog post can be found in the Workarounds for a related issue: [Multiple Select Does Not Return Correct Form Data During Callback](http://connect.microsoft.com/VisualStudio/feedback/details/594413/multiple-select-does-not-return-correct-form-data-during-callback)